# get user list in admin area

Tags: admin

how can I fetch a list of registered users and show it in the admin panel. I know theres the list inside the admin panel already but I've added a few tables and I need to show them in a new tab menu inside the admin panel.

Comment: what do you mean by new tables?

Comment: Sorry meant to say that I've added a few extra fields onto the users table.

Comment: adding columns to the users table is most certainly a bad idea, this is what user meta data is for.

Comment: I **STRONGLY** suggest you use User Meta rather than Columns in the user table. This is incredibly bad practice

Comment: why is it bad practice - I would be creating more code to handle a simple get? more code = less performance doesn't it?

Comment: you should never modify anything in core, changing the schema could produce unpredictable results and an update could overwrite your changes.

Comment: It is not more code, because you can remove the table alteration code, get_user_meta is a 1 liner, no global $wpdb or calling the mysql functions directly, and the added benefit of having all the DB caching and the object caching logic built in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've done is incredibly bad practice, and should be undone immediatley. There is already a dedicated table for storing user details aka User Meta. Altering the user table could cause issues with other plugins and Core, prevent upgrades working, and bypasses all the caching and object stores WordPress puts in place. It also adds additional avenues for SQL injections.

TLDR: Never modify Core WP Tables

Instead use the provided User Meta API:

- [get_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)
- [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)
- [delete_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta)

They work in the same way get_post_meta etc work, and there is already a dedicated table, and additional APIs for querying via `WP_User_Query`.

Then display this using the answer here:

[How to display multiple custom columns in the wp-admin users.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/how-to-display-multiple-custom-columns-in-the-wp-admin-users-php)

To search for users based on meta use the [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) class. Using this you can grab lists of users with specified meta data, e.g.

```
$args = array( // get all users where
    'meta_key' => 'specialkey', // the key 'specialkey'
    'meta_compare' => '=', // has a value that is equal to 
    'meta_value' => 'helloworld' // hello world
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( !empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

Comment: whats different from using users table than using meta table, slightly confused?

Comment: Modifying the user table is horrendously bad practice. NEVER modify core tables, use the provided APIs and datastructures and take advantage of the caching and helper functions provided to you. Modifying the user table could hurt performance, make upgrades fail, is nonstandard, and uses raw SQL queries.

Comment: Also the meta table was built specifically for storing additional user details, many people spent many hundreds of manhours testing refining and debugging, can you really do a better job with a handful of extra columns?

Comment: hmm encase you misunderstand, you shouldn't be adding columns to the user meta table either, user meta has key value pairs attached to a user ID

Comment: ok I now understand...apologies wordpress, I suppose I need help storing 4 string sets and 2 datetime's inside the meta table?

Comment: `update_user_meta($user_id,'date1',time());`

Comment: `$thatdate = get_user_meta($user_id,'date1');`

Comment: so this method would store each string/date as a key inside the meta table? also which field would it store it in?

Comment: which field is irrelevant, you wont and shouldn't be doing raw sql queries, there is no need, and it bypasses the object cache, which is very bad. use get_user_meta and add_user_meta/update_user_meta. If you need to find all users with X meta etc use WP_User_Query in the same way you'd use WP_Query or query_posts. If you need to touch the database and do SQL, you've done something very wrong

Comment: I've added an example of WP_User_Query. As I said, always use the APIs, there is no reason for you to do wpdb calls or raw mysql calls, modify tables, or access tables directly. Doing so is bad practice, and will cause you more not less trouble, and deprive you of optimisations and features you would normally have.

Comment: @user1888564 Any progress on this question? Did it help you? If so, please mark it as solved.